# How to use a service with data from Json file, Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have a json file and I'm trying to put this data in a service in Angular 2.

**my code is:**

my todo.service.ts:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';   
@Injectable()
 export class TodoService {
   constructor(public http: Http) {}
   todos = [];
   getTodoData() {
     console.log('so bad');    
     this.http.get('./data.json').subscribe(res => {
        this.todos.push(...res.json());
      });
     return this.todos;
  }
}
```

my app.component.ts is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {TodoService} from './todo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
myjsondata: any;
title = 'app';
todos= [];
constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {
  this.todos = todoService.getTodoData();
}
}
```

my data.json :

```
{
    "todos": [{
            "id": 1,
            "content": "order the room",
            "isDone": false
        },
        {}
    ]
}
```

my app.component.html:

```
<div>
    <h1>Todos List : </h1>
    <insert></insert>
    <div>
        <p *ngFor="let item of todos">{{item.content}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting an error:
"zone.js:2933 GET http://localhost:4200/data.json 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: So your json file is currently in the same folder as your component, is that correct?

Comment: Make sure that dist folder (which is located on your live-server) contains your json files. If not, you need to configure webpack. You could also move the mock data to `/assets/mock-data/data.json` and adjust the url

Comment: Also, returning an empty array and populate it later is really really not a good way of handling asynchronism. Just return an observable, and subscribe to the observable from your component.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your data.json file in assets folder.
2. Change url in your http.get method to:
   http://localhost:4200/assets/data.json

Answer (score 0):

**Loading the json file**

You are trying to load your json files as if it was placed in the same folder as your application. This can be true for your local project structure, but an angular application is usually shipped to the frontend (usually the browser) and not all files that you see on your local file system are included in this bundle, including json files if they are not placed in the right folder, which is why the file cannot be found (404).

What you can do is place your file in the assets folder which is usually next to the app folder (if you have such a thing) and then use the path to `assets/data.json` for example. Here's what the http call can look like:

```
this.http.get('assets/data.json').subscribe(res => {
    this.todos.push(...res.json());
});
```

**Asynchronous Http call**

As someone else noted in a comment under your question, there is also a problem with how your receive and return your json result. The angular Http module works aysnchronous, meaning that your code is not executed one line after the other. Let's take a look at your code:

```
getTodoData() {  
  // this call is asynchronous 
  this.http.get('./data.json').subscribe(res => {
     // this code may be executed much later
     this.todos.push(...res.json());
  });
  // this code may be executed way before your todos are loaded
  return this.todos;
}
```

What you can do to improve it is to return the `Observable` that is returned from the http call and subscribe to that in your component instead of your service. There you can easily set your todos. Let's take a look.

*todo.service.json*

```
getTodoData() {
    // make the call, but return the whole Observable object
    return this.http.get('./data.json');
}
```

*app.component.ts*

```
todos = [];
constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {
    // subscribe to the getTodoData call
    // when the result returns, set your todos directly
    todoService.getTodoData().subscribe(res => {
        this.todos.push(...res.json());
    });
}
```